# can't select any element on infalted layout

Tags: java, android

I have an inflated layout that appears when I select a GeoPoint, the inflated layout has a button on it and I can't seem to be able to click the button and have spent hours trying to figure out why and have done this to no avail. Below shows the code where the inflated layout is invoked and also the onClick for the button is shown.

```
      public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.place_detail, null);
                String pos = arg0.getSnippet(); //get index of the marker data

                Button accept = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);

                accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HAPPY MAN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });                 
                try{
                    int ipos = Integer.parseInt(pos);
                    PlaceData data = mListPlaceData.get(ipos); //get the data by index
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtName)).setText(data.name); //show name of the place
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtHours)).setText("Hours: "+data.hours); //show hours of the place
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCountry)).setText("Country: "+data.country); //show country of the place
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress)).setText("Address: "+data.address); //show address of the place
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtPostCode)).setText("Postcode: "+ data.postcode); //show postcode of the place
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
                return v;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to show custom info view on clicking the map's marker?

Comment: yes it is custom info and there is also a button with id 'button3'. I want to be able to click the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

Source:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

Comment: that makes sense on why I couldn't click the button! I will try and implement this now :) I'm kind of a novice at this but I will give it a good go!

Comment: Your button will not detect any click. The entire layout is rendered as a single image. You can only give listener for the entire info window!

Comment: can i create a click event for the entire image that I have at the minute? means I can use all the code I have at the minute without having to make any changes?

Comment: you mean the infowindow? If so, Yes you can. `googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() { @Override public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) { }});`